# Recommendation for good book or online course on distributed programming

Tags: distributed-systems

I am a computer science student in his final year on the university with several years of experience in software engineering. I want to take me to the next level in programming web applications.
I am looking for a good book or online course on the subject of distributed programming with in-depth understanding, and how to design and build large and scaled web applications professionally like facebook, amazon, google from scratch.

By the way, I will be happy to hear also about a good book or online course which explain about all the new technologist that web application can connect/interact with like: AI analysis, databases, cloud computing and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is awesome book:
Designing Data-Intensive Applications
[https://www.amazon.com/Designing-Data-Intensive-Applications-Reliable-Maintainable/dp/1449373321](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449373321)

You may find the review here:
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23463279-designing-data-intensive-applications